# Angularjs controller: Cannot set property 'query' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am new to Angular. I want to set a variable `query` to `null` and `imgType` to `"illustration"` in my controller, but it throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'query' of undefined".

Do you know what's wrong? Otherwise everything works

I am using AngularJS 1.4.3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ilustracka">
        <!--Controller-->
        <div ng-controller="SearchController as searchCtrl" ng-cloak>
            <!--Searching-->
            <form ng-submit="searchCtrl.search()"> 
                <input type="text" ng-model="searchCtrl.query" placeholder="search...">
                <select ng-model="searchCtrl.imgType">
                    <option value="illustration" selected>ILU</option>
                    <option value="image">IMG</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
            </form>

            <!--Summary result--
            <summary></summary>-->

            <!--Result-->
            <output></output>      
        </div>

        <!--JavaScripts-->  
        <script src="libs/angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/ilustracka.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/searchController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/outputDirective.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/searchApiService.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ilustracka')
        .controller('SearchController', SearchController);

    //load service searchApi
    SearchController().$inject['searchApi'];

    function SearchController(searchApi) {
        var vm = this;
        /*
         * vars
         */
        vm.query = null;//search string
        vm.imgType = 'illustration';//type of search image - (ilu|img)
        vm.images = null;//result of query - empty object
        vm.result = null;//showing result or info message
        /*
         * functions
         */
        vm.search = search;


        function search(){
            //!empty searchQuery
            if(vm.query){
                searchApi.searchImg(vm.query, vm.imgType); 
                vm.images = searchApi.getImages();
                vm.result = searchApi.getResult();
            }            
        }   
    }
}());
```

ilustracka

```
(function(){
    "use strict";   
    angular
            .module("ilustracka", []);
}());
```

Comment: can you make a plunker or jsfiddle? would be easier to debug

Comment: Incorrect dependency injection of the searchApi.

Comment: `$inject` should be used on the controller constructior function, not its instance: `SearchController.$inject = ['searchApi'];` (no parentheses).

Comment: @plamut `SearchController.$inject['searchApi']` will literally do nothing. Should be `SearchController.$inject = ['searchApi']`.

Comment: @dfsq Sorry, typed too fast, thanks for noticing. I fixed my comment. (focused too much on the parentheses, but forgot to fix the other issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you inject `searchApi` service into your controller. `$inject` is not a method but property and correct syntax should be:

```
SearchController.$inject = ['searchApi'];
```

With your original code `SearchController().$inject['searchApi'];` it threw unhandled error because `SearchController()` (result of function invocation) returns `undefined` and undefined has no property `$inject`. However, it doesn't prevent further controller instantiation, but then new error happens - unknown provider due to missing dependency injection. And this prevents correct controller instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

//You have to create your app module passing a dependency array, empty or not.
angular.module('ilustracka', []) //add empty brackets

http://jsbin.com/riyozu/edit?html,js,output

```
   (function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('ilustracka', [])
    .controller('SearchController', ['searchAPi', function (searchApi) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.query = null;//search string
      vm.imgType = 'illustration';//type of search image - (ilu|img)
      vm.images = null;//result of query - empty object
      vm.result = null;//showing result or info message
      function search() {
        if (vm.query) {
          searchApi.searchImg(vm.query, vm.imgType);
          vm.images = searchApi.getImages();
          vm.result = searchApi.getResult();
        }
      }
      vm.search = search;
    }]);
}());
```

Comment: Not if your app is already created before, in `scripts/ilustracka.js` I guess.

Comment: Your search was declared before defined, I moved under the definition, see it that works for you

Comment: and i don't think you need to inject $scope since you are using your Controller As class, as suggested by DevVersion

Comment: But why he recommends my way https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#bindable-members-up-top? And in jsbin your method throws an error.

Comment: I am not getting error on my screen. What type of error are you getting?